# Check if web service is online, but don't make a instance

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-services

I have two projects: 1 is a WCF web service and 1 is a Windows Service.

In the global of my web service I call a method which will send a email to me when I start the web service.

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailService mailService = new MailService();
        mailService.SendConfirmationMail();
    }
```

In my Windows Service I check every 5 minutes if the web service is online. If not I send a email.

```
    public void CheckWebserviceTimer()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(300000);
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
             ...
        }
    }
```

But when the web service is online and I start the Windows Service then the code `var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);` makes a new instance of the web service. And when `var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();` is called, I get a new email. (This happens only the first time when the timer is elapsed) But I don't want that. I only want to know if the web service is still alive or not.

Is there a solution for this problem?

**EDIT:**
For the complete code to check if multiple webservices are online: See my answer!

Comment: De Windows Service is intended to be a watchdog

Comment: The webservice (application) isn't actually started before a request is made hence you get the email when the watchdog makes the request. You probably should move your code to `Application_Init` instead.

Comment: I see. I started a other application which sends data to the webservice and after that I started the Windows Service and I didn't get an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webservice isn't actually started before a request is made hence you get the email when the watchdog makes the request. See [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The solution I'd go for is to NOT have the webservice email when it starts but instead have the watchdog email when the status of the webservice changes.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that. I have multiple webservices and in the watchdog I am going to check every single webservice. Now I don't have for every webservice a method which will send an email, but only one method in the watchdog.

Comment: Exactly. You encapsulate the functionality in a single place which will make the code (and system) easier to understand, maintain and debug.

Comment: I updated my code. See my answer! It works really wel.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a very good solution with help from @Sani Huttunen

In my Windows Service:

```
public partial class NotificationStarter : ServiceBase
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        WebserviceController webserviceController = new WebserviceController();
        webserviceController.FillWebservicesList();
        webserviceController.CheckWebserviceTimer();
    }
}


public class WebserviceController : ConfigurationSection
{
    private List<WebserviceConfig> _webservicesList; 

    [ConfigurationProperty("Webservices", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(WebservicesCollection),
        AddItemName = "add",
        ClearItemsName = "clear",
        RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public WebservicesCollection Webservices
    {
        get { return (WebservicesCollection)base["Webservices"]; }
    }

    public void FillWebservicesList()
    {
        WebserviceController contoller = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("WebservicesSection") as WebserviceController;

        if (contoller != null) 
            _webservicesList = contoller.Webservices.Cast<WebserviceConfig>().ToList();
    }

    public void CheckWebserviceTimer()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(300000);
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var webservice in _webservicesList)
        {
            try
            {
                var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(webservice.Value);
                var response = (HttpWebResponse) myRequest.GetResponse();

                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && webservice.IsOnline)
                {
                    ...
                    webservice.IsOnline = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    webservice.IsOnline = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public class WebservicesCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new WebserviceConfig();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((WebserviceConfig) element);
    }
}


public class WebserviceConfig : ConfigurationElement
{
    public WebserviceConfig()
    {
    }

    public WebserviceConfig(string name, string value, bool isOnline)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        IsOnline = isOnline;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true, IsKey = false)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string) this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("value", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true, IsKey = false)]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return (string) this["value"]; }
        set { this["value"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("isOnline", IsRequired = true, IsKey = false)]
    public bool IsOnline
    {
        get { return (bool) this["isOnline"]; }
        set { this["isOnline"] = value; }
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="WebservicesSection" type="NotificationDispatcher.WebserviceController, NotificationDispatcher"/>
  </configSections>
  <WebservicesSection>
    <Webservices>
      <add name="Webservice1" value="http://localhost:1234/Webservice1.svc?wsdl" isOnline="false" />
      <add name="Webservice2" value="http://localhost:4567/Webservice2.svc?wsdl" isOnline="false" />
    </Webservices>
  </WebservicesSection>
</configuration>
```

The two webservices named in the app.config file will go to the `_webservicesList` when I start the Windows Service.

If I make a new webservice then I only have to do is add one row in the app.config. And every 5 minutes the Windows Service will check every webservice if it is still online.